# JQuery Stop Animation queue (multiple click)

Tags: jquery, html, events

I'm creating a sample static slider which have 20% div left and right (space to display a part of the next or prev slide ) and 60% in center that contain the main slide;

so , the slider must be somthing like

**|20%|60% main slide|20%|** : I have to keep those percentage fixed.

When clicking once , everthing works fine ,otherwise when I click on one of those divs more then one simultanious click the main slider should only move 60% (right or left ) but it triggers more then one call so the main slide move randomly !

How to prevent multiple click function call till the annimation is being finished.

Snippet :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $("#slide-right").on( "click", function(event){
  event.stopImmediatePropagation
  slide('right');
 });
 
 $("#slide-left").on( "click", function(event){
  event.stopImmediatePropagation
  slide('left');
 });
});

function slide(direction){
 
 var slider_width = $("#slide_container").width();
 $( ".slide" ).each(function( index ) {
  var elmnt_left = $(this).position().left;
  //alert(this.id)
  
  var val = 100 * elmnt_left / slider_width;
  var percentage = 0;
  
  // direction slide to left
  if(direction == 'left'){
   if(index == 0) {
    if(val > -100)
     percentage = val - 60;
   }   
   else if(index == 1) {
    if(val > -40)
     percentage = val - 60;
   }    
   else if(index == 2){
    if(val > 20)
     percentage = val - 60;
   }
  }else if (direction == 'right'){ // direction slide to right
   if(index == 0) {
    if(val < 20 )
     percentage = val + 60;
   }   
   else if(index == 1) {
    if(val < 80)
     percentage = val + 60;
   }    
   else if(index == 2){
    if(val < 140)
     percentage = val + 60;
   }
  } 
  
  console.log()
  
  if(percentage !== 0){ 
   $( this ).animate({
    left: percentage+'%'
   }, 400, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    
   });
  }
  
 });
};
```

```css
html,body {
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 margin:0px;
}

.main{
 width:100%;
}

#slide_container{
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:300px;
 overflow:hidden;
 text-align:center;
}

#slide_container .slide {
 position:absolute;
 width: 60%;
 border:0px solid #ccc;
 height:100%;
 display:inline-block;
 margin:0;
 opacity:0.7;
}

#slide_container .slide1 {
 background-color:green;
 left:20%;
}

#slide_container .slide2 {
 background-color:gray;
 left:80%;
 
}

#slide_container .slide3 {
 background-color:pink;
 left:140%;
 
}


#slide_container  #slide-left {
 display:inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 left:0;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:100;
}

#slide_container  #slide-right {
 display:inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 20%;
 right:0;
 position:absolute;
 z-index:100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="main">
  <div id="slide_container">
   <span id="slide-left"></span>
   <span id="slide-right"></span>
   <div>
    <div class="slide slide1" id="1" ></div>
    <div class="slide slide2" id="2" ></div>
    <div class="slide slide3" id="3" ></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: *"simultaneous click"* do you mean a double click?

Comment: BTW you're doing it wrong, you should not animate every .slide element, but a single parent container.

Comment: can you explain more please !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to prevent multiple click function call till the annimation is being finished?

Pseudo code:

```
$("#next").on("click", function(){
   if( $("#slider").is(":animated") ) return;
   // animation logic here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a class in the container when the animation starts and remove the class when the animation ends.So this class is only present while the animation is taking place.

When `slide` function executes you can check if that class is present, and if it is, return false.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $("#slide-right").on( "click", function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation
    slide('right');

});

$("#slide-left").on( "click", function(event){
    event.stopImmediatePropagation
    slide('left');

});
});

function slide(direction){

if($("#slide_container").hasClass("animating")) {
return false;
}else{
$("#slide_container").addClass("animating");
}

var slider_width = $("#slide_container").width();
$( ".slide" ).each(function( index ) {

    var elmnt_left = $(this).position().left;
    //alert(this.id)

    var val = 100 * elmnt_left / slider_width;
    var percentage = 0;

    // direction slide to left
    if(direction == 'left'){
        if(index == 0) {
            if(val > -100)
                percentage = val - 60;
        }           
        else if(index == 1) {
            if(val > -40)
                percentage = val - 60;
        }               
        else if(index == 2){
            if(val > 20)
                percentage = val - 60;
        }
    }else if (direction == 'right'){ // direction slide to right
        if(index == 0) {
            if(val < 20 )
                percentage = val + 60;
        }           
        else if(index == 1) {
            if(val < 80)
                percentage = val + 60;
        }               
        else if(index == 2){
            if(val < 140)
                percentage = val + 60;
        }
    }   

    console.log()

    if(percentage !== 0){   
        $( this ).animate({
            left: percentage+'%'
        }, 400, function() {
            // Animation complete.
             $("#slide_container").removeClass("animating");
        });
    }

   });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(percentage !== 0 && !window.animating)
{   
        $( this ).animate({
            left: percentage+'%'
        }, {
             start: function(){
                window.animating = true;
             },
             complete: function(){
                window.animating = false;
             }
         });
    }
```

Adding a var in something "global" like `window` could do the trick in my opinion.